# React Functional Component OnClick Event Scope Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While creating an array of table data, I'm trying to pass the current ID of an image into a function using an onClick event. What am I doing wrong here? I had the impression a simple solution such as this.id or an event handler would function correctly. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
        function deleteRecord(event)
        {
               alert(event.target.id);       
        }

        let j = 0; 
        for(let i in dataRes)
        {
            j++;
            arr.push
            (
                    <tr>
                        <td><div><img id={j} src={"RANDOM IMAGE"} onClick={(event)=>deleteRecord(event)} /><span id={"item"+j}>{DATA}</span></div></td>
                        <td>{DATA}</td>
                        <td>{DATA}</td>
                    </tr>
            );
        }
```

Comment: @frozen  "Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals"

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the onClick event into the function, when all you need to pass is the value of `j`. However, we want to pass the value of `j` at the point in the loop, so we need to make a copy of `j` before passing it in.

So right after `j++;`, we need to create a new copy `let j_copy = j;`

Then your onClick function should be:

```js
onClick={()=>deleteRecord(j_copy)}
```

and your `deleteRecord` function:

```js
function deleteRecord(index)
{
      alert(index);    // alerts the value of j_copy 
}
```

This hard-codes the value of j each time the loop runs. Note that each time the loop runs, a new HTML fragment with a different onClick handler gets generated with that hard-coded value. So the first time, it's equal to `onClick={()=>deleteRecord(1)}`, the second time it's `onClick={()=>deleteRecord(2)}`, and so on.

Comment: How does the onClick have access to the variable j? Isn't it out of scope?

Comment: no, `j` is in-scope when you pass it to `deleteRecord` because you're accessing it inside the for-loop

Comment: Does it hardcode the value of j at that specific iteration in the loop. I had the idea that the value of j that would be passed into the function would be the final value of j at the end of the loop.

Comment: Yes, it will hard-code the value of `j` each time the loop runs. Note that each time the loop runs, a new HTML fragment with a different onClick handler gets generated with that hard-coded value. So the first time, it's equal to `onClick={()=>deleteRecord(1)}`, the second time it's `onClick={()=>deleteRecord(2)}`, and so on.

Comment: On my end it alerts only the final value of j, this isn't correct...

Comment: Your solution isn't functional it only sends in the terminal value of the loop. @frozen